# Parenthesis URL dispatcher Django?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have a parenthesis in my url :

Ex: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacramentum_(oath)

Where The URL has parenthesis.

Django give """Page not found (404)"""

Any idea how to solve this problem ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you have a URL pattern in urls.py that looks something like this (to use your example):

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^wiki/Sacramentum_(oath)/', my_view),
)
```

This won't match, because parentheses have a special meaning in regular expressions. You need to escape them with backslashes:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^wiki/Sacramentum_\(oath\)/', my_view),
)
```

Comment: Scaramentum_(oath) is just a example of the data stored in ""Variable" .. 
@Ghopper21 : Can i do anything like this (?P< Variable >\w+) which does any magic ???

Like RAW_URL ..

Comment: @dilipray, yes you can -- that's the main normal use of parentheses in Django URL patterns. I think I'm not understanding your underlying issue or problem. What URL pattern are you trying to match? And what part of the pattern are you trying to capture in a view parameter?

Comment: The Example :
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacramentum_(oath),
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog_(disambiguation),
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India_(Vega_album),
And i have few more titles..

So, my question is can use (?P< Title(Which Contains The Above Example)>\w+) URL dispatcher

Comment: `url(r'^wiki/.*\((?P<param>.*)\)/'` should do it, with the text within the parenthesis being passed to the view as `param`

Comment: In other words, it works as normal. The unescaped parentheses `(` and `)` denote a captured parameter for the view; the escaped parentheses `\(` and `\)` match the URL like any other part of the regex.